# bind-Value does not update value in time

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the following code for a generic search component. It just has an `InputText` and a Search button. The search should get triggered when clicking on the search button or when I hit enter while being in the search textbox. The issue is that when I press the Enter button and my event is invoked, the `_searchTerm` string is not updated in time, and the old value is returned to my parent component. When I click the button, everything is working fine. How could I solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```cs
@using System.Runtime.CompilerServices
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
        <InputText id="searchTerm" @onkeydown="@Enter" @bind-Value="_searchTerm" class="form-control" placeholder=" " />
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="TriggerSearch">Search</button>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string?> OnSearchTriggerd { get; set; }

    private string? _searchTerm;

    private async Task TriggerSearch()
    {
        await OnSearchTriggerd.InvokeAsync(_searchTerm);
    }

    private async Task Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
        {
            await TriggerSearch();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `onKeyUp` instead of `OnKeyDown`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeydown` now and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the input on each keystroke so that you can submit the entered value.  Here's how:

First the `SearchComponent`:

```cs
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Enter Your Search"
           @bind=_searchTerm
           @bind:event="oninput"
           @onkeydown=this.TriggerSearch>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"
            type="button"
            @onclick=this.DoSearch>
        Button
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> Search { get; set; }

    private string? _searchTerm;

    private Task DoSearch()
        => this.Search.InvokeAsync(_searchTerm);

    private async Task TriggerSearch(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
            await this.Search.InvokeAsync(_searchTerm);
    }
}
```

We bind the input to `_searchTerm` and define that it's updated on every keypress by defining `@bind:event="oninput"`.  This ensures that if we click on the button we call `Search` with the correct string.

We handle *Enter* by defining `@onkeydown=this.TriggerSearch` where  `TriggerSearch` checks for the key code and only calls `Search` on the appropriate codes.

I've changed the formatting to show how to do the combo input and button as a Bootstrap `inputgroup`.

Here's a demo page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<SearchComponent Search="this.DoSearch" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre> Search : @_searchTerm</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string? _searchTerm;

    private async Task DoSearch(string? term)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        _searchTerm = $"{term} found at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

Also note that I don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  If you aren't an async expert don't use it: keep it simple, just await.  In this case it does nothing.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` was a ReSharper misconfiguration as I am a Backend developer, that's my default. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: No problem.  It's a bit of a pet subject.  Too many people complicate async without understanding the consequences

Answer (score 0):

You can use input with these settings. This results in the bound member _searchTerm being updated immediately every time the user changes the value in the input.

```
<input id="searchTerm" @onkeydown="@Enter" 
       @bind-value=@_searchTerm @bind-value:event="oninput" 
       class="form-control" placeholder=" " />
```